# How to do special handling for the last term in the TokenStream generated by WhitespaceTokenizer

Tags: java, lucene

My use case - if a Roman numeral comes at the very end of a TokenStream, then convert it to English numeral. Otherwise let it be.

Ex. "Something III" >>> "Something 3". 
But "III Something" >>> "III Something" (remains same as III does not come at the very last)

How exactly do I make this logic work in Lucene?

p.s. input.incrementToken() seems to return true first, and then false for every term in the TokenStream generated by the WhitespaceTokenizer.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to have just a bit more detail ? The piece of code ?

I suppose you already took a look at this :

http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenStream.html

Saying :

"Consumers (i.e., IndexWriter) use this method to advance the stream to the next token"

It is normal that your incrementToken returns false the second time, since you are not having any space next.

You must loop with end() to know when the string is done (excuse my french, i don't see how to write it).

Comment: From the doc (the same link as in my post) : "Implementing classes must implement this method and update the appropriate AttributeImpls with the attributes of the next token" -> there is the way to handle your tokens